# C# сортировка generic IEnumerable от List<int>

Tags: c#, linq

У меня в методе есть переменная `IEnumerable items`, в которую приходит любая из моделей, с целью отсортировать ее по `Position`, пример:

```
if(sort == Sort.ASC){
    items = items.OrderBy("Position ASC");
}else{
    items = items.OrderBy("Position DESC")
}
```

Если явно указать модель `var cars = items as IEnuberable<Cars>;`
То потом можно объявить `List<int> ids` со списком чисел и сделать такое:

```
cars = cars.OrderBy(x => ids.IndexOf(x.Id);
```

Но если у меня таких моделей 20+ штук, то делать так каждый раз - это много лишнего кода(но пока могу только так).

Можно ли это как то правильно написать, не указывая каждый раз модель?

Comment: У Вас во всех 20+ моделях есть поля `Position` и `Id`? Если да, то сделайте для них интерфейс и реализуйте в каждой модели. Далее используйте `IEnumerable<ISpecialFields> items = cars;` и 1 сортируйте.

Comment: `.OrderBy("Position ASC")` - вы какую-то библиотеку используете, где можно поля строкой задать? Или это псевдокод? / `.OrderBy(x => ids.IndexOf(x.Id)` - не ясно, как это связано с первой частью вопроса. Смотрите метод `Array.Sort` - есть перегрузки, принимающие два массива: ключи и значения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это есть в Linq.Dynamic. OrderBy(this IEnumerable source, string ordering, params object[] values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дайте угадаю.
Вам нужно в `.OrderBy(x => ids.IndexOf(x.Id)` использовать свойство `Id` у разных классов, не имеющих общего предка/интерфейса?

Думаю, такой метод позволит решить вашу задачу:

```
IEnumerable<T> GenericSort<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Sort sort, Func<T, int> func)
{
    if (sort == Sort.ASC)
        return items.OrderBy(x => ids.IndexOf(func(x)));
    else
        return items.OrderByDescending(x => ids.IndexOf(func(x)));
}
```

Здесь `ids` поле класса, но можно сделать `List<int> ids` ещё одним параметром метода.

Вызывать следующим образом:

```
var sortedCars = GenericSort(cars, Sort.ASC, car => car.Id)
```

Вместо `cars` может быть коллекция любого типа. Соответственно, вместо `car.Id` объект с любым подходящим свойством.